# Refactoring near identical linq queries where the where clause is different

Tags: linq, refactoring, dry

I have two methods that are almost identical. The only  dffernece is the where clause (and method name). I have just included a simplified linq query.

```
from tableA in db.tableA
join tableB in db.tableB on tableA.id equals tableB.id
where tableB.ref == "blah"
select tableA
```

and

```
from tableA in db.tableA
join tableB in db.tableB on tableA.id equals tableB.id
where tableB.refb == "blah"
select tableA
```

Is there a way I can make the where change? I know I could remove there where  from the query then after the results are returned use .notation to filter. (May need to do some other stuff to make sure the field I need from tableB is returned).

Is there a better way? Does it matter that I have two linq queries that are almost identical apart from the where?

Comment: Do these need to be separate calls? Can you not use where tableB.ref == "blah" || tableB.refb == "blah"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes refactor it to this

```
var data = from tableA in db.tableA
           join tableB in db.tableB on tableA.id equals tableB.id
           select tableA

var one = data.Where(x=>x.ref == "blah");
var two = data.Where(x=>x.refb == "blah");
```

This way you can you query in one palce and just filter that main query

Comment: This may have performance implications because you are performing in-memory subqueries on a full result set (returned by the previous query).

Comment: @ArnoldZokas no you're not. The query hasn't been executed yet.

Comment: Agreed its deciding what is the lesser of two weavels

Comment: `Where` needs a capital `W` by the way.

Comment: @Arnold: no it won't. LINQ uses deferred execution and will yield the same performance characteristics as the original query.

Comment: @Leigh: this won't work, since `TableA` does not contain properties `ref` and `refb`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless performance is a concern, you could keep them as they are now.
These look like simple queries and refactoring them would make the code less readable.

Comment: I don't agree if you have to change the query you will have to make that change in multiple places : (

Comment: I would say it depends on usage and performance requirements.